# suspicious job offer

Tags: job-search, job-offer

So basically I got offered a job verbally and was told that at the interview that they would like to offer me the position. They even introduced me to everyone in the team saying I will join the team in a couple of weeks.

They asked me to wait for a couple of weeks to get the paper work done. I contacted them in a couple of weeks and they reduced the offer because they said that they did not get the permission for what they originally offered. Not only that, they said they dont really need me but are just agreeing to keep me in board in somewhat of a good will gesture. They also said that if I find another job I should go for it. I asked them some time to think about it and then emailed them to ask them for a written offer to which they did not respond since a day. Can someone tell me what is it that they are trying to do and whether I should consider working for this place?

Actually im an international student and I am just about to graduate. Thus I could need the job and the employer told me in the second interview that I wont be able to get a job anywhere else

Comment: If you don't understand why your question was be closed or don't agree with it, you're more than welcome to ask for a more detailed explanation or make a case about it on [meta], or make your case in the comments or by editing your question. Simply asking the same question again is a frowned-upon strategy.

Comment: This question was determined to be off topic here, asking it again isn't going to change the fact that it doesn't meet our guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

They're trying to get you as cheap as possible, or they have decided they don't need you.

Either way, keep job hunting.